# What did I miss in my Mock Aspect configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I am developping a phpcas bundle using [guard component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#the-guard-authenticator-methods) of Symfony framework. My bundle is working but I want to do some unit tests. I want to test my CasAuthenticator. [PhpCAS library](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS) is using static method. So I decided to use [Mock Aspect](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock) to mock it.

I configured Aspect, but I still have a bug.

Here is a simplified test which is running but failing.

[image: Screenshot of the failing test]

> Expected PhpCAS::setDebug to be invoked but it never occurred. Got:
>
> C:\wamp64\www\casguard\casguard\vendor\codeception\aspect-mock\src\AspectMock\Proxy\Verifier.php:64
>
> C:\wamp64\www\casguard\casguard\Tests\SimpleTest.php:32

```
//root_dir/Tests/SimpleTest.php
namespace AlexandreT\Bundle\CasGuardBundle\Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use AspectMock\Test as test;
use PhpCAS;

class SimpleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testAspectMock()
    {
        $phpCas = test::double('PhpCAS', ['setDebug' => function () {
            echo 'YES I CALL THE MOCKED Debug function';
        }]);
        PhpCAS::setDebug();
        $phpCas->verifyInvoked('setDebug', false);
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        test::clean();
    }
}
```

Output does not contain *YES I CALL THE MOCKED Debug function*, so I think that the PhpCAS is not mocked by Aspect.

I carefully read [this documentation](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/10/php-getting-aspectmock-to-work.html) and I configured my bootstrap file like this:

```php
//root_dir/Tests/bootstrap.php
include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; // composer autoload

$kernel = \AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'debug' => true,
    'includePaths' => [
        __DIR__.'/../vendor/jasig/phpcas', 
    ],
]);
```

As you can read, I added the vendor directory where the `Cas.php` declares the PhpCAS class. But it doesn't change anything. I made some tests: the bootstrap.php file is loaded by phpunit.

**What did I miss in my Mock Aspect configuration?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a line to configure cache directory in my `bootstrap.php` file
and I can see that the `Cas.php` was well included.

But I still had the bug. When I was exploring the cached file, I discovered that the phpcas library doesn't respect the PSR0 convention. First letter of phpCAS Class isn't capitalized.

So I edited my test:

```php
public function testAspectMock()
{
    //$phpCas = test::double('PhpCAS', ['setDebug' => function () {
    //                        ^
    //                        | 
    //                        v
      $phpCas = test::double('phpCAS', ['setDebug' => function () {
        echo 'YES I CALL THE MOCKED Debug function';
    }]);
    phpCAS::setDebug(); //phpCAS instead of PhpCAS
    $phpCas->verifyInvoked('setDebug', false);
    //And I had an assertion else test is marked as risky.
    self::expectOutputString('YES I CALL THE MOCKED Debug function');
}
```

2 letters... 2 hours of debugging... #Grrrr